# Как отключить логгирование msi установщика в системный журнал?

Tags: wix, msi

Я создал msi установщик моего программного обеспечения при помощи wix инструмента. Я использую интеграцию с Microsoft_VC140_CRT.msm. В ходе установки на Win 10 х64 возникает ошибка и установщик отменяет сделанные в системе изменения. При этом установщик отмечает в системном журнале предупреждение о том, что приложение предприняло попытку установки более ранней версии защищенного файла С:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll. Индентификатор события 1030.

Как отключить логгирование msi установщика в системный журнал?